# Convert Oracle 12c database from WE8MSWIN1252 to utf-8 character set

Tags: oracle, plsql, utf-8, character-encoding, oracle12c

I've been tasked with giving my project manager development/test estimates. We are converting our Oracle12c database from a character set of WE8MSWIN1252 to utf-8 characters.

I've been tasked to come up with development change estimates on the following.

1. Switch datatype from Byte to Char (i.e. VARCHAR2(10 **byte**) to VARCHAR2(10 **char**) )
2. changing code where **Length** needs to be replaced by **lengthb**

**My Questions.**

1. Do I only have to worry about changing database table columns from byte to char? or are there other objects on the database I might need to look at?
2. Is Length to Lengthb the only Pl/SQL function I need to look at?
3. As a developer is there any other areas I need to look at (i.e. We have Oracle forms/reports)?
4. I noticed the below code can Alter all the tables columns in **user_tab_columns** do I need to run this for other object types and objects that are not fetched by the below query.

> ```
>    BEGIN
>     FOR X IN (SELECT C.TABLE_NAME, 
>                      C.COLUMN_NAME,
>                      C.DATA_TYPE,
>                      C.DATA_LENGTH
>                 FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS C
>                WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE 'VARCHAR%' 
>                 AND CHAR_USED = 'B'
>                 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USER_VIEWS V WHERE V.VIEW_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME))
>     LOOP
>         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('ALTER TABLE '||X.TABLE_NAME||' MODIFY '||X.COLUMN_NAME||' '||X.DATA_TYPE||'('||X.DATA_LENGTH||' CHAR)');
>     END LOOP;
>     END;
> ```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you take a read of note 225912.1 on support.oracle.com.

There may be a fair bit involved in changing the characterset, including scanning for existing data that might need to reloaded/altered etc.